# why can't I move a std::unique_ptr of a boost timer into a capture clause?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, boost-asio

When I try to call async_wait on a boost::basic_waitable_timer that has the std::unique_ptr in the capture clause, I get errors. Take the following example:

```
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using steady_timer = asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::steady_clock>;
asio::io_service ios;
std::thread([&ios] {
    asio::io_service::work w(ios);
    ios.run();
}).detach();


std::unique_ptr<steady_timer> timer = std::make_unique<steady_timer>(ios);
timer->async_wait([t = std::move(timer)](const system::error_code& ec) {
    std::cout << "timer hit " << "err:" << ec.message() << std::endl;
});
```

This code gives me the following compiler errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2338   WaitHandler type requirements not met   cpp_rest_test   e:\development\boost_1_65_0\boost\asio\basic_waitable_timer.hpp 509 
Error   C2280   'timer_test::::(const timer_test:: &)': attempting to reference a deleted function   cpp_rest_test   e:\development\boost_1_65_0\boost\asio\basic_waitable_timer.hpp 509 
Error   C2280   'timer_test::::(const timer_test:: &)': attempting to reference a deleted function   cpp_rest_test   e:\development\boost_1_65_0\boost\asio\basic_waitable_timer.hpp 509
```

The boost error leads me to this:

> ```
> // If you get an error on the following line it means that your handler does
> // not meet the documented type requirements for a WaitHandler.
> BOOST_ASIO_WAIT_HANDLER_CHECK(WaitHandler, handler) type_check;
> ```

I am using msvc140 compiler.

Comment: Can Boost.Asio take move-only types?

Comment: Moving from and dereferencing the `unique_ptr` in the same statement isn't good. You can't tell whether the move constructor or the `operator->` will be called first.

Comment: [The documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Handler.html) says "A handler must meet the requirements of *CopyConstructible* types". The lambda you pass to `async_wait` isn't copyable, thanks to having a member of type `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you, don't know how i overlooked that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that would simply mean it shouldn't compile. Which isn't always the case. See [Movable Hanlders](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/move_handlers.html) in the docs

Comment: @sehe It's not just that Boost documentation says that the handler must be *CopyConstructible* - Boost implementation explicitly checks that the handler meets the requirements. *That's* what prevents the code from compiling, not an attempt to use the missing copy constructor. Boost doesn't simply lay down the rules, it actively enforces them, using a concepts-like machinery.